# Problem adjusting JQuery Menu Width with CSS

Tags: jquery, css

Im having some issues trying to adjust the Width of some of the items for this JQuery Menu that I downloaded from here:  http://apycom.com/menus/6-midnight-blue.html

The CSS is very complex, but I was able to narrow down the Width for the entire Menu, but the other parts have been difficult to track down.

I would like to have the overall Menu width about the same size as the Red Div marked below it.

The slider itself- which moves as you hover over the main menu items is too wide, and Im not sure how to adjust that.

The last menu item "Request Estimate" appears to have no padding at all, and it looks cramped compared to the other menu items.  It is the longest spelled word and thats why, but I would like to figure out a way to slightly reduce the size of the other Main Menu Item widths.

The Sub Menu Box is almost twice the width of the Main Menu Items, and I have no idea how to reduce the width for this.

With limmited CSS knowledge I seem to messing things up, more than fixing anything.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the CSS which came with the JQuery download, and I have made adjustments to this:

```
/* menu::base */
div#menu {
    height: 51px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    background: url(images/left.png) no-repeat;
    _background: url(images/left.gif) no-repeat;
    width:auto;    
}

div#menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
div#menu ul.menu {
    padding-right: 14px;
    background: url(images/right.png) no-repeat right 0;
    _background: url(images/right.gif) no-repeat right 0;    
}

div#menu li {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0px 0 0;
    /*background: green;*/
    display: block;
    float: left;
    z-index: 9;
    width: auto;
}
div#menu ul ul li {
    z-index: 9;
}
div#menu li div {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 11;
    top: 51px;
    left: -3px;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 194px;
    margin: 0px 0 0 -4px;
    padding: 0; 
    background: url(images/subsubmenu-top.png) no-repeat 0px 0;
    _background: url(images/subsubmenu-top.gif) no-repeat 0px 0;  
}
div#menu ul ul {
    z-index: 12;
    padding: 0px 4px 10px 4px;
    background: url(images/submenu-bottom.png) no-repeat 0px bottom;
    _background: url(images/submenu-bottom.gif) no-repeat 0px bottom;        
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;    
}
div#menu li:hover>div {
    visibility: visible;
}

div#menu a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    /*width: auto;*/
    width: 90px; /*adjust overal menu width*/
    padding-right:5px;
    text-align:center;
}
div#menu span {
    margin-top: 2px;
    /*padding-left: 15px;*/
    padding-left: 2px;
    color: #A6C4D5;
    font: bold 12px Arial,Helvetica;
    background: none;
    line-height: 50px;  
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 95% 0;
    text-align: center;
}

/* menu::level1 */
div#menu a {
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    line-height: 50px;
    height: 51px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    _margin-right: 1px;
    background: none;
}
div#menu a:hover {
    background:  url(images/selected.png)  repeat-x right -1px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
div#menu li.current a,
div#menu ul.menu>li:hover>a {
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    background: url(images/selected.png)  repeat-x right -1px;
}

div#menu ul.menu>li:hover>a span {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
div#menu li {  }
div#menu li.last { background: none; }

/* menu::level2 */
div#menu ul ul li {
    background: none;
    padding: 0;
}
div#menu ul ul a {
    padding: 0px;
    height: auto;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    line-height: 25px;
    z-index: -1;
    padding-left: 5px;
    white-space: normal;
    width: 164px;
    margin: 0 8px;
    text-transform: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #3A5A8B;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #162133;        
}

div#menu ul ul a span {
    font-weight:normal;
    padding: 0 5px;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #C5D3E7;
}
div#menu li.current ul a,
div#menu li.current ul a span {
    background:none;
}
div#menu ul ul a:hover {
    background:none;
    background-color: #21345A;
}
div#menu ul ul a:hover span {
background:none;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
div#menu ul ul a.parent {
    background: url(images/submenu-pointer.png) no-repeat right bottom;
    _background: url(images/submenu-pointer.gif) no-repeat right bottom;  
}
div#menu ul ul a.parent span {
    background:none; 
}
div#menu ul ul a.parent:hover {
    background: url(images/submenu-pointer.png) no-repeat right bottom;
    _background: url(images/submenu-pointer-hover.gif) no-repeat right bottom;
    background-color: #21345A;
    color: #FFFFFF;  
}
div#menu ul ul a.parent:hover span {
    background:none; 
}
div#menu ul ul span {
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
div#menu ul ul li.last { background: none; }
div#menu ul ul li {
    width: 100%;
}

/* menu::level3 */
div#menu ul ul div {
    /*width: 194px;*/
    padding: 0;
    margin: -51px 0 0 192px !important;
    margin-left: 192px;
}
div#menu ul ul ul {
    padding: 10px 4px 0 4px;    
}
div#menu ul ul div li {
    position:relative;
    top:-10px;
}

/* lava lamp */
div#menu li.back {
    background: url(images/selected.png) repeat-x 0 0;
    width: 5px;
    height: 51px;
    z-index: 8;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0px 0 0 0;
} 

div#menu li.back .left {
    padding:0;
    width:auto;
    background: url(images/selected.png) repeat-x right 0;
    height: 51px;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="DaVincisApp1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="menu.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/menu.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div style="margin-left:1em; margin-top:5em;">
        <div id="menu">
       <ul class="menu">
           <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Home</span></a>
      <div><ul>
         <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Sub Item 1</span></a>
        <div><ul>
           <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Sub Item 1.1</span></a>
           <div><ul>
              <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 1.1.1</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 1.1.2</span></a></li>
           </ul></div>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 1.2</span></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 1.3</span></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 1.4</span></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 1.5</span></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 1.6</span></a></li>
           <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Sub Item 1.7</span></a>
           <div><ul>
              <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 1.7.1</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 1.7.2</span></a></li>
        </ul></div>
                     </li>
        </ul></div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 2</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 3</span></a></li>
    </ul></div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>About Us</span></a>
       <div><ul>
       <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Our Core Values</span></a>
          <div><ul>
             <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 1.1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 1.2</span></a></li>
          </ul></div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Company History</span></a>
           <div><ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 2.1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 2.2</span></a></li>
           </ul></div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Our Process</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Our Credentials</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Our Guarantee</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Why DaVinci's</span></a></li>
        </ul></div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Services</span></a>
                  <div><ul>
                     <li><a href="#"><span>Residential</span></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><span>Faux Painting</span></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><span>Wallpaper Services</span></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><span>Commercial</span></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><span>Drywall Services</span></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><span>Powerwashing</span></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><span>Painter-For-A-Day</span></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><span>Priority Service</span></a></li>
                  </ul></div>
               </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Porfolio</span></a>
                  <div><ul>
                     <li><a href="#"><span>Interior Gallery</span></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><span>Exterior Gallery</span></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><span>Faux Gallery</span></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><span>Commercial Jobs</span></a></li>
                  </ul></div>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"><span>Testimonials</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Client Area</span></a>
                  <div><ul>
                     <li><a href="#"><span>Start-up Guide</span></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><span>Color Selector</span></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><span>Painting Facts</span></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><span>Paint Glossary</span></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><span>Jobsite Safety</span></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><span>Forms/ Checklists</span></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><span>Online Payment</span></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><span>Privacy Policy</span></a></li>
                  </ul></div>
               </li>
    <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>Request Estimate</span></a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
</div>
<br /><br /><br />
<div style="width:44em; margin-left:1em; background-color:red">About this size</div>
<a href="http://apycom.com/"></a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should really be asked in http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: is there a live link by any chance I can go to? It's so much easier to understand than wade through this or download the plugin, create files, etc.

Comment: I wish I could just post a pic of it, but I dont have enough points yet.

Comment: @Paul: Post a link and someone will edit it in for you.

Comment: @ThirtyDot I dont have this on a development server, and I cant post a pic, I could email a pic.

Comment: @Tim - no, this is a dev question. StackExchange "...is not about...
Developing web applications"

Comment: I've been struggling with this all day, making adjustments to the various padding and widths of the CSS, unfortunately its not well commented.

Comment: The Demo shows the functionality of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to have the overall Menu
>   width about the same size as the Red
>   Div marked below it.

Just give your `div#menu` the same witdh as the red div. And set to `div#menu ul.menu` to `100%`

> The Sub Menu Box is almost twice the
>   width of the Main Menu Items, and I
>   have no idea how to reduce the width
>   for this.

The width of the nested menu items are changeable in `div#menu li div`. Set width to your needs. Note that you also have to edit the width of `div#menu ul ul a`

An working solution based on your code can be viewed here: http://jsfiddle.net/xPkcZ/1/

**Note:** On some background properties i've added an background-color like `#ddd` for better view results because the background images are note available.

Comment: For the 2nd issue: I changed the width for (div#menu li div) AND for (div#menu ul ul a)  both widths to 150px, however not all of the width gets adjusted.  I tested this with your example:  http://jsfiddle.net/xPkcZ/1/

Comment: This CSS is really crappy ;) The Trick was to change also the left margins in `/* menu::level3 */ div#menu ul ul div` to 145px

Comment: (div#menu li div) width 150px; (div#menu ul ul a) width 150px;  (div#menu ul ul div) width 145px;   That still doesnt work ;-(

Comment: sorry for (div#menu ul ul div) margin-left: 145px; didnt work.  It appears that the outer box is the right size, however the 3rd level of the menu is offset to the right by alot of space.  The inner portion of the sub-menu where the actual text is located "sub item1" that width hasnt changed.

Comment: Paul are you reading my comments? You should not set a with to div#menu ul ul div. I told you to set left margin. As you can see here everything works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/xPkcZ/6 . Normally you can copy the code form my example. I've changed only the values above.

Comment: sorry I had missed this margin: (margin: -51px 0 0 145px !important;) That works, thanks for helping me out with this!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out 1 width issue with the Menu's Main Level and with that the Slider that moves across each item.

```
div#menu li {
position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 0px 0 0;
/*background: green;*/
display: block;
float: left;
z-index: 9;
/*width: auto;*/
width: 100px; /*adjust width for each Level1 item*/
}
```

Now Im looking for a solution for the Sub-Menu below the Main Menu

Comment: I just commented on your other post, its too wide.